# Entity Framework Core 6 - custom model for stored procedure results

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'd like to create a custom model that doesn't already match one of my SQL tables, to hold the result data from a stored procedure.

I can add a DbSet for my procedure like this...

```
public DbSet<ustp_MyProcResults> ustp_MyProc { get; set; }
```

and add the entity to `OnModelCreating` like this...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ustp_MyProcResults>().HasNoKey()
```

However, when I run add-migration, it always writes up a `CreateTable` script for my procedure (`ustp_MyProc`).

Obviously this is not intended to be a table, so I don't want the migration to do this.

I have read that I can just add the following to the `OnModelCreating` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ustp_MyProc>().HasNoKey().ToView(null);
```

This does work. The migration no longer tries to create a table, but is the accepted method? Is this the proper way to work with custom models like this?

Comment: Why do you need a model?  Don't you just want a class object?  Entity uses a mapping between the c# clases and the database.  The mapping is one to one.  So Migration will create tables in the database for each class in the model.  You want a class that is not in the Model.

Comment: Last I heard `HasNoKey().ToView(null)` is the (or at least *is an*) accepted method (aka workaround) still.

Comment: In reply to jdweng - When running the procedure, I need it to map to some kind of data structure.  It's very common for procedures to contain many joins and return columns from multiple tables.  I'm not just querying against a single table.

Comment: With EF Core 8 you no longer need a DbSet for this.